# Is there a way to combine these 2 loops?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

Is there a way to combine these two loops to make it more efficient?

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i + 1, n + 1):
        print(i, j)
```

Thanks!

Comment: editing it now.

Comment: Why do you think "combining" them would make anything "more efficient"?

Comment: If your purpose is to make them more efficient then use list comprehension or generator    For e.g  ((i,j) for i in range(n) for j in range(i + 1, n + 1))

Comment: Actually, it's efficient enough. If you combine them, the time the program runs will not obviously decrease.

Comment: I can't think of an easy way off the top of my head, but it seems as though a loop through `range(n * n)` might work.

Comment: Just run list comprehension and normal code for a larger value of n to get the time effiency.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is efficient enough with respect to fact that it is understandable and readable to others hence it is recommended.

However If you are looking for a one liner in python then you can use the following one but I strongly do not recommend it as it only makes the code more un-readable and only adds a headache to others

```
n = 10
print(' \n'.join('{} {}'.format(*item) for item in [ (i,j) for i in range(n) for j in range(i+1,n+1) ]   ) )
```

This prints out the exact same output as the code that you have provided.

Comment: `if i < j` is unnecessary as `j` is defined to be from `i+1` and upwards.